# One-way ANOVA model

Tags: anova

How do I combine 2 factors from a two-way ANOVA model into 1 factor in a one-way model? Do I take the factor with the most effect on the model, or consider both factors in? 
For example, if I used factor A and B in the 2-way model, let's say the response variable depends more on factor A, do I only include factor A in the 1-way model?

Answer (score 0):

You don't do this. That is, you don't "combine" the two factors.  You may want to drop one, but that's a different question.

Comment: So is it right I only include the one factor that has the most effect on the response variable?

Comment: No. Or, at least, you haven't given us enough information. There can be reasons to drop a variable, but you could equally well just want to keep a two-way ANOVA.